# Understanding Debian versus LinuxMint, finding version numbers

Tags: debian, linux-mint, version

As I understand it LinuxMint is built on top of Debian.  Mint seems not to give me the most up-to-date version of the Haskell compiler GHC, but to download the binaries for the most recent stable version I need to know my Debian version.  I looked around for how to find it but all I get are results like

```
$ cat /etc/*-release
DISTRIB_ID=LinuxMint
DISTRIB_RELEASE=18.3
DISTRIB_CODENAME=sylvia
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Linux Mint 18.3 Sylvia"
NAME="Linux Mint"
VERSION="18.3 (Sylvia)"
ID=linuxmint
ID_LIKE=ubuntu
PRETTY_NAME="Linux Mint 18.3"
VERSION_ID="18.3"
HOME_URL="http://www.linuxmint.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://forums.linuxmint.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.launchpad.net/linuxmint/"
VERSION_CODENAME=sylvia
UBUNTU_CODENAME=xenial
cat: /etc/upstream-release: Is a directory
```

and

```
$ cat /proc/version
Linux version 4.15.0-38-generic (buildd@lcy01-amd64-023) (gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10)) #41~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 10 20:16:04 UTC 2018
```

Is every LinuxMint version associated with a Debian version, or do I need to do something else to figure out the Debian version?

Comment: I don't know anything about this, but `UBUNTU_CODENAME=xenial` looks pretty informative here.

Comment: Canonical makes two releases of Ubuntu per year, based on currently unstable/testing Debian, and they call it stable without any further testing. Clem also changes the background of the desktop, changing the title of installer and set cinnamon as the default desktop environment. It tooks about some weeks for him, then he releases the new linuxmint called as he wants.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just run

```
cat /etc/debian_version
```

in the terminal. 
This gives you the Debian version, i.e., 'Stretch' would be v9. 
See [Debian version history](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian_version_history) and [Debian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian) on Wikipedia.

Comment: [sid](https://www.debian.org/releases/sid/) is **not** the stable branch. It's a mixed [frankendebian](https://wiki.debian.org/DontBreakDebian).